# IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, iis

While I try to send a contact message on my website, I'm getting the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed</title> <style type="text/css"> <!-- body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} .config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} .summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} a:hover{text-decoration:none;} h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; }#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; }#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} .summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} .content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; }#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; }#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; }#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; }#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; }#details-right th{width:20%;} table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} .highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} .clear{clear:both;} .preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} --> </style> </head> <body> <div id="content"> <div class="content-container"> <h3>HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed</h3> <h4>The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.</h4> </div> <div class="content-container"> <fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> <ul> <li>The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the module configured to handle the request.</li> <li>A request was sent to the server that contained an invalid HTTP verb.</li> <li>The request is for static content and contains an HTTP verb other than GET or HEAD.</li> <li>A request was sent to a virtual directory using the HTTP verb POST and the default document is a static file that does not support HTTP verbs other than GET or HEAD.</li> </ul> </fieldset> </div> <div class="content-container"> <fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> <ul> <li>Verify the list of verbs enabled for the module handler this request was sent to, and ensure that this verb should be allowed for the Web site.</li> <li>Check the IIS log file to see which verb is not allowed for the request.</li> <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> </fieldset> </div> <div class="content-container"> <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> <div id="details-left"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;StaticFileModule</td></tr> <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;StaticFile</td></tr> <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x80070001</td></tr> </table> </div> <div id="details-right"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://www.ericbartolo.com:80/api/contact.php</td></tr> <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;d:\web\localuser\ericbartolo.com\public_html\api\contact.php</td></tr> <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> </table> <div class="clear"></div> </div> </fieldset> </div> <div class="content-container"> <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> This error means that the request sent to the Web server contained an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the configured module handler for the request. <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=405,0,0x80070001,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p> </fieldset> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php



$configEmail = "hello@ericbartolo.com";

  // My modifications to mailer script from:
  // http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form

  // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection
  // Only process POST reqeusts.
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
      $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
              $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
      $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
      $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
  // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
  if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
      http_response_code(400);
      echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
      exit;
  }

  // Set the recipient email address.
  $recipient = $configEmail;

  // Build the email content.
  $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
  $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
  $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

  // Build the email headers.
  $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

  // Send the email.
  if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
      // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
      http_response_code(200);
      echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
  } else {
      // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
      http_response_code(500);
      echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
  }

} else {
  // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
  http_response_code(403);
  echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

Comment: There isn't a 405 being thrown in this code! 405 btw means you use the wrong method like GET when it needs POST, or any of the other HTTP verbs like DELETE PATCH etc

Comment: Looks like your IIS is misconfigured and it going to some default GET page

Comment: @delboy1978uk how do I change it from my hosting? Thanks

Comment: Sorry amigo I don't use IIS, however there is a link in that error HTML showing you how to trace the request and see where it ended up. also check your logs